# vim -X flag as .vimrc entry

Tags: vim, xserver, tmux

Is there a config entry I can place in my .vimrc which will achieve the same as passing the `-X` flag when running vim.

To provide some context:
I recently found that my vim startup time in a screen (tmux) session was extremely long (~6 seconds)

Using the `vim --startuptime` flag, it is clear that the issue is due to the connection to the X server in order to setup the X clipboard.

Running `vim -X` has fixed my slow startup time. I would prefer to modify my .vimrc, rather than creating a bash alias to solve this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may want to take a look at the `clipboard` setting (`:help 'clipboard'`). What follows is a recommendation from Gary Johnson ([source](http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/slow-startup-in-gnu-screen-td1176250.html#a1176255), [via web.archive.org](http://web.archive.org/web/20200319142123/http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/slow-startup-in-gnu-screen-td1176250.html#a1176255)).

---

You may want to set 'clipboard' in your .vimrc so that you don't 
have to use -X all the time. In my situation, I use vim on a 
machine that I log in to from various other machines, some of which 
have $DISPLAY set even though they don't have an X server. Here is 
what I have in my .vimrc:

```
" Prevent vim from trying to connect to the X server when connecting 
" from home, which causes a startup delay of about 14 seconds. I 
" usually connect from home via screen. 
" 
"set clipboard=autoselect,exclude:cons\\\|linux\\\|screen 
" 
" Using $DISPLAY instead of 'term' should be more reliable. It avoids 
" the problem of starting vim without first starting screen and allows 
" screen to be used locally without losing vim's X features. 
" 
if $DISPLAY =~ '\(\(cos\|scs\)\d\+nai\d\+\)\|\(spkpc\d\+\)\|\(tc-garyjohn\)' 
set clipboard=autoselect,exclude:.* 
endif
```

---

(Do notice that you'll need to tweak the `if $DISPLAY` line to match your own `$DISPLAY` variable).

Comment: For cygwin: set clipboard=autoselect,exclude:cons\\\|linux\\\|screen\\\|rxvt\\\|cygwin. Thanks!

Comment: Source link is dead.

Answer (score 3):

Just add to your **~/.vimrc**

```
set clipboard=exclude:.*
```

Do this mainly to you root user. Other users should work fine connecting the `$DISPLAY` and clipboard.

Comment: This will stop the `No protocol specified` error when running a GUI enabled instance of vim under root.